# Maven - Non-resolvable parent POM

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build with Maven from Eclipse and it does not work even though it does when I run it from command line. In Eclipse I'm using the same settings.xml, the same Maven and the same JRE.

The log is the following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/()
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ line 8, column 11
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for (project name): Could not find artifact (artifact name):pom:1.0.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 18, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project (project name):${project.version} (My pom.xml's full path) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for (project name):${project.version}: Could not find artifact (artifact name):pom:1.0.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 18, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

It is missing the project's pom.xml's parent pom which is stored in an artifactory. I have access to the artifactory.

- The artifactory is declared in the `.m2/settings.xml`
- I can find it in the `.m2/repository` directory
- I'm using `JRE 1.8`
- I'm using `Maven 3.6.0`

**Cleaning the project and updating Maven does not work.**

Comment: You are using an parent `artifact name):pom:1.0.3 in central` ..which does not exist in central...

Comment: How shall I tell it not to use the central but the one that I declared in the settings.xml?

Comment: Are you working in a corporate environment?

Comment: Yes, but at the moment there is no one near to help

Comment: I assume that your parent is a project of your own? Or is this a multi module build? Within a corporate environment you should use a repository manager...where you can store such artifacts which have been produced internally...

Comment: As far as I'm concerned that parent project or pom is in Artifactory. The one that i want to build is not a multi module build but there's some that are multi module but for sure, all projects have this same "pipeline-mvn-parent" parent.

Comment: Ok than you have to configure your `settings.xml` accordingly to use your artifactory which obviously is not the case.

Comment: You were right. The problem was with the settings.xml. Eclipse uses two different settings.xmls: a global and a local. The local is set automatically but the global xml is not. It has to be referenced manually. Thank You!

Comment: The global should usually never being touched. The local settings inside `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` should be configured correctly. If you change the global settings this will break future updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `settings.xml`. In Eclipse Maven uses two settings: global and local settings which can be set at

> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings

The `Global Settings` should be where Maven is intalled /conf/settings.xml and the `User Settings` should be the user directory /.m2/settings.xml